# A question about infinitie series and pi

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity, pi

This is the sequence that can be used to find an exact value of pi

4/1−4/3+4/5−4/7+4/9−4/11…..(to infinity) =

Or   (1/1−1/3+1/5−1/7+1/9−1/11….. (to infinity) )=  /4

Given that we have this result, is it possible to find the value of the sequence 1-3+5-7+9-11….. ?

Comment: No. $................$

Comment: @RonGordon Um.. Thanks I guess...

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the “normalized” value of [$\beta(-1)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function), use $\beta(-k)=\dfrac{E_k}2$, where $E_k$ is the $k^{th}$ [Euler number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number).